# angular examples break when changing display from list to table

Tags: angular, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to angular so I'm probably missing something very obvious. I created a project using this excellent tutorial, https://sniederm.wordpress.com/2017/04/12/tutorial-ng2-rest-service/ and it works fine. Then I tried to modify the code to display the data in a table instead of in a list. Before:

```
<div>
  <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let user of users | async">{{user.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

After:

```
<table>
      <tr ng-repeat="user in users | async">
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

But when I display the project, there's an error in the debugger: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

Can anyone please help explain why I'm getting this error?

Thanks,

Jade

Comment: Well why would change to AngularJS syntax when you are using Angular, makes no sense? :D

Answer (score 0):

The syntax your using is from AngularJS not Angular. `ng-repeat` is now `*ngFor`

Update the code to the following

```
<table>
      <tr *ngFor="user in users | async">
        <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```